# Can you explain what is Heliocentric velocity

Tags: galaxies

[image]

In this photo, What is the meaning of heliocentric velocity ?

Is the velocity at which the Sun's motion was corrected or before the Sun's motion was corrected?

Comment: from grammar and meaning, the sun the center,i.e motionless, and the NGC3198 moving with this velocity

Comment: @anna v. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heliocentric means, the sun is considered the unmoving center.

Comment: thanks